# Buttons keep disappearing as I try to add more

Tags: java, android

So basically my program is supposed to create a button in a separate activity each time another button is clicked. However every time I add a button the previous button I added disappears (the buttons move across horizontally).

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import android.widget.GridLayout.LayoutParams;

import java.util.Arrays;


public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static int count = 0;
public static int x = 100;
//public static int[] xPos = new int[5];
public static int y = 100;
private boolean stopper = true;
public static int spot = 0;
//public static Button[] buttonArr = new Button[5];
public static LinkedList<Button> buttonList = new LinkedList<Button>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    int b = getIntent().getIntExtra("bob", 0);

    //System.out.println(b);
    if(b==-11978182){
        //System.out.println(buttonList.size());
        //for(int i = 0; i<buttonList.size(); i++) {
            //RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
            //Button addButton = new Button(this);
            //if(stopper) {
                //buttonList.add(addButton);
                //stopper = false;
            //}
            //System.out.println(buttonList.size());
            RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
            Button addButton = new Button(this);
            addButton.setId(spot);
            buttonList.add(addButton);
            System.out.println(buttonList.size());
            buttonList.get(spot).setText("add");
            RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
            layoutParams.setMargins(100*(spot+1), 100, 100, 100); // left, top, right, bottom
            buttonList.get(spot).setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            //RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);

            //for(int i = 0; i<buttonList.size(); i++) {
                mainLayout.addView(buttonList.get(spot));
                mainLayout.addView(layout);
            //}
            spot = spot + 1;
        //}
    }

    Button galleryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    galleryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity.this,Test2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are adding buttons to the same location one on the another. Your button aren't getting disappear, it's just you are rendering new button on the previous one.

You can do it correctly in many way like changing the location of the new button one after the other like keeping horizontal position as same and changing vertical position (Make sure you have scroll view in your layout).

Or, use a RecyclerView in which the child has a button only. Each time you need a new button, you just add a new child at the bottom of the RecyclerView.

Comment: I am able to print out the button in different locations and overtime it comes out it a different location the previous button disappears. Therefore I still think the buttons are disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

try this will work for you

copy this in your xml layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/ll_main">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/click"
    android:text="click"/>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_add_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_add_btn);
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            Button button1 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
            button1.setLayoutParams(lparams);
            button1.setText("added");
            linearLayout.addView(button1);
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Your xml file doesn't seem to work. I am getting various tag issues.

Comment: add this at the bottom </LinearLayout>

Comment: Thank you! Do you know of a way to get your code to print buttons in another column or row? It appears it only prints buttons in one direction and I'm not sure how to adapt it so that it will move to another line once a button has been pressed.

Comment: if ma answer is correct you can give a up vote infront of ma answer

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and you are only adding one button in code.
And the for loop is slashed and can't be run at this time.
Also if you open for loop, you are using Relative layout. so in this case, you have to set the buttons left or right object id.
Please try like this.

1. Please remove slash and use for loop.
   And please change RelativeLayout to LinearLayout.
2. If it doesn't work, please change the spot default value.
   I never used object id as 0, so not sure it can be work.

Comment: Okay I changed all of that but I'm still getting an error because now it's giving me a RunTime Error and saying that I am trying to call addView on a child without calling removeView on its parent. I'm not sure how to go about fixing that. Do you have any ideas?